# Add combo box, drop down or list box in data gridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Do you know how i could add a combo box, drop down or list box in a specific cell in a data grid view. i have tried with this code but it doesn't work--

```
DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
c.Items.Add("A");
c.Items.Add("B");
c.Items.Add("C);
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Rows[1].Cells[1] = c;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer--

```
//create columns as textbox columns(or whatever you want)
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgc1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

            //add the colums to the table
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgc);
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dgc1);
            //set header text here if you wish

            //create dgv combobox cells and add items to the collection
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbc = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cbc.Items.Add("item 1");
            cbc.Items.Add("item 2");
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cbc1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();
            cbc1.Items.Add("item 1");
            cbc1.Items.Add("item 2");

            //create 2 rows here so that you can insert future columns without having them go above your comboboxes
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);

            //set row one cells to combobox cells
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] = cbc;
            dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1] = cbc1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn c = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
c.Items.Add("A");
c.Items.Add("B");
c.Items.Add("C);
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns.Add(c);
```

Comment: thx for replaying, but this code creates a column with combo box, i need a specific cell to be a combobox. Say that i want row[1] column [1] to be a combobox